# Intellij turn off code folding involving tilde/squiggle/twiddle (~)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I cannot figure out how to turn off the code folding action in Intellij IDEA which collapses types and so forth with the green squiggle. In other words, you might have a line like:

`private ArrayList listPlots = new ArrayList<~>();`

where the "~" squiggle is the folded code. How do I disable this folding?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Settings > Editor > Code Folding > "Generic constructor and method parameters"

FYI, the settings window has a pretty good search field at the upper-left. I just typed "fold" into that and it was a pretty quick search after that.

Comment: This has no effect on the folding as given in the example from the question.

Comment: Worked for me. Try it with a file you haven't opened yet. It looks like IntelliJ remembers what it's folded and what it hasn't, and it remembers those values regardless of whether you set them manually or they got defaulted in. Invalidating caches seems to clear that and have the new settings take effect for all files.

Comment: @yshavit your comment is what I needed - very frustrating that the setting does not at least warn you this may be necessary. I had to both close the file THEN invalidate the cache. IDEA 12.1.6 Ultimate

Comment: Thank you! On a personal note, I hate this folding feature, when I want that, I'll activate it myself.

Comment: Does anyone have an IDEA 14.1.7 update? The menus are different and doing a search for "fold" or "folding" in the Settings doesn't work.

Comment: @NoniA. I'm on 2016.3, but in that one it's Editor > General > Cold Folding, then that same checkbox. It would be odd if searching for "fold" worked in 2013 (when I posted this) and works now, but didn't work in 2015 (when 14.1.7 came out). Maybe try searching for "generic constructor and method parameters" ?